# HTML5 camera image to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my mobile app first uses the camera element of html5 and then takes a picture. The picture then shows on a seperate div. I'm having problems naming the image & then saving both the image and the caption to localstorage. Are my attempts futile, or is there a way to do this?

Thank you for any help or guidance offered.

Comment: Show us the code you have used so far, so that we have something to work with.

Comment: i think you have to submit the images through form post for security reasons, then you can make a base64 of it and  store in local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save an image in localstorage you need to convert it to dataURL string. You can do this via the canvas element as shown below.

When you want to retrieve the image from localstorage and display it you can simply set the src attrib of an image element to the dataURL string.

```js
// convert image to localstorage friendly data URL string
function getImageDataURL(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  return dataURL;
}

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  var dataURL = getImageDataURL(image);
  document.body.innerHTML = dataURL;
  image.src = dataURL;
  document.body.appendChild(image);
};
image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
image.src = '//placekitten.com/g/120/120';
```